# Array- looping through secondary array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

Unable to get the index from the second array to match the first array

```
// array constants 
const int people = 7;
const int phoneNumbers = 7;

int main() {
  char person, family; 
  int index; 
  string found;
  int size =7;

  //array declaration and set values
  string people [] ={"Darryl","Jasmine","Brian","Duane","Ayana","Mia","Maya"};

  // const char phoneNumbers  = 7;
  string phoneNumbers[] = {"678-281-7649", "818-933-1158", "212-898-2022", 
  "361-345-3782","817-399-3750","313-589-0460","818-634-4660"};

  //set boolean value
  found = "False";

  //initialize index 
  index = 0;

  // search variable and user input 
  cout << "who are you looking for?     " << endl;
  cin >> people[index];
  for (index=0; index<=6; index--) {
    if (people[index] == people[index] )
    cout << "phone num for " << people[index] << " is  "<< 
    phoneNumbers[index] << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I put in Jasmine which is the `people[]` array, the `phoneNumbers[]` array brings back the first index of `phoneNumbers[]` which it should bring back the second index on `phoneNumbers[]` array

Comment: What do you expect for `people[index] == people[index]`? Always true.

Comment: validating that the input from user matches the people[index] content.  How can I make sure the input from user matches the people[index] and then loopup the phone number to match

Comment: `//initialize index 
index = 0;` - Why didn't you just do that when you declared `index`??

Comment: `cin >> people[index];` Your user input overwrites your reference data...

Comment: I'm a student and still learning .. do u mean initialize index like this - index =  people[index]

Comment: I got it .. thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit .. when u stated that .. I changed  cin >> input;  then redid my loop  for (index=0; index<=6; index++)
 {
  if (input == people[index] )
  {
   cout << "phone num for " << people[index] << " is  "<< phoneNumbers[index] << endl;
  }

Comment: @T'hishaSmith Better

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here.

- You are replacing content of the people[0] with the cin - so first item of the array will be always user's input.
- You are decrement index, so the FOR cycle goes to the indexes 0,-1,-2... This is problem as arrays in C and C++ goes from 0 to upper values.

I would prefer to add one variable:

```
string input;
```

then:

```
cin >> input;
```

for cycle should be used:

```
for (index = 0; index < 6; index++)
```

and in your condition I would use:

```
if (person[index] == input) ...
```

Comment: Format your post. Look at it before submitting. Help options and information are provided on the posting interface for when you are unsure how to. Take your time. Get it right.

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner way of doing this would be too use `std::map` provided by the C++ standard template library. Below is my take on what you're trying to achieve:

```
// phoneNumber.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{   
    // delcare a map variable that maps people's names to phone numbers
    std::map <std::string,std::string> lookUpPhoneNumber = {
        {"Darryl", "678-281-7649"},
        {"Jasmine", "818-933-1158"},
        {"Brian", "212-898-2022"},
        {"Duane", "361-345-3782"},
        {"Ayana", "817-399-3750"},
        {"Mia", "313-589-0460"},
        {"Maya", "818-634-4660"}
    };

    // take input name
    std::string inputName;
    // user prompt
    std::cout << "who are you looking for?: ";
    std::cin >> inputName;

    // look up name in map
    if(lookUpPhoneNumber.find(inputName) != lookUpPhoneNumber.end()){
        std::cout << "Phone num for " << inputName << " is: " << lookUpPhoneNumber[inputName] << "\n";
    } else{
        std::cout << "Name does not exist!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

To compile and run, use the following command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o phoneNumber phoneNumber.cpp
./phoneNumber
```

Or check your compiler option to enable compiling with `c++11` standard or higher.